# Content Slider Issues javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok everyone so I'm trying to make a visual code like www.gamespot.com. I have a show/hide/toggle function for each div.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2ZswK/1/)

Javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//<!--

function showRow(mainsect){
if (document.getElementById(mainsect)) {
        document.getElementById(mainsect).style.display = ''; 
    }
}

function hideRow(mainsect){
if (document.getElementById(mainsect)) {
    document.getElementById(mainsect).style.display = 'none';
}
}

function toggleRow(mainsect){
if (document.getElementById(mainsect)) {
    if (document.getElementById(mainsect).style.display == 'none') {
        showRow(mainsect)
    } else {
        hideRow(mainsect)
    }
}
}


//-->
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function('hideRow';) {
toggleRow('mainsect');
};
</script>
```

Ok and the html i am using for each div is

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onMouseOver="toggleRow('sect')" onMouseOut="toggleRow('sect')">Page 1</a></li>
```

and what this does is when it mouseOver togglesRow 'sect' and i have multiple of these ////\ javascript codes, four i believe, to call each different div. Problem is the style="display:none;" makes it so there is no image at all. What I'd like to is make it so when it mouses out of sect or Page1 it stays on that until mouseover page2 or anyother page...how do i do this?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing this as an exercise, otherwise there are plenty of these available: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/freebies/javascript-sliders-scrollers/

Comment: no not for practice and at the same time yes. I can only use javascript right now, i do not know jquery. And i'd rather have the sense of pride of designing this myself to actually work. and all those examples aren't exactly what I want.

Comment: since everyone uses jsfiddle on here I gave it a whirl. heres the fsfiddle preview. only thing is i want the sections to stay. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/2ZswK/1/ as well as onpageload i want it the mainselecter

Comment: Alex I see you had edited this. what did u edit?

Comment: If you click on "3 hours ago," you can see. I just added a link to your jsFiddle in the question.

Comment: oh ok thats it. lol sorry my bad. So im still having many problems with this code haha. I just want it to work the way i need it to. what if I make a if (toggleRow(row1)==true{

Answer (score 0):

ok i got everything to work. What I did was delete the

```
} else { 
    hideRow(mainsect) 
}
```

Which was making it hide everytime mouse over function was called on even if the div was already opened which i did not want. So then in turn created the a hrefs like this

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onMouseOver="toggleRow('sect')";hideRow('otherRow');hideRow('sect2');">Page 1</a></li>
```

everything is working fine and dandy. Though while in a jsfiddle it does not work, so trying to figure more out.